# Python overloading multiple getitems / index requests

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have a `Grid` class which I want to access using `myGrid[1][2]`. I know I can overload the first set of square brackets with the `__getitem__()` method, but what about the second.

I thought I could achieve this by having a helper class which also implements `__getitem__` and then:

```
class Grid:

    def __init__(self)
        self.list = A TWO DIMENSIONAL LIST       

    ...

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return GridIndexHelper(self, index)

class GridIndexHelper:

    def __init__(self, grid, index1):
        self.grid = grid
        self.index1 = index1

    ....

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.grid.list[self.index1][index]
```

This seems a little too homebrewed... What is the python way to achieve this?

Comment: why don't you use  `myGrid[1,2]` numpy-like syntax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class Grid:

    def __init__(self):
        self.list = [[1,2], [3,4]]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.list[index]

g = Grid();

print g[0]
print g[1]
print g[0][1]
```

prints

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
2
```

Comment: I actually want to do some validation of the indexes etc so that doesn't work unfortunately. thanks though

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see why you cannot "do some validation of the indexes etc". You can validate the first index in `def __getitem__(self, index)`. The second index will be validated by the python `List` class. If you want to validate the second index, use `MyListClass` of `MyListClass` in `self.list` where MyListClass is a  List subclass where you can have your own validation.

Comment: ahh yes.. i could make a custom list anf put the other __getitem__ in there.. obvious really, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you really meant this comment, the red light has turned on in my sarcasm detector :) Anyway, believe me, it is more straightforward and pythonic to subcalss the list then this `GridIndexHelper`.

Comment: Ahh, you're too cynical. There was no sarcasm intended, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know the way anajem mentions is the only way.

example:

```
class Grid(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.list[index[0]][index[1]]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mygrid = Grid()
    mygrid[1, 1] #How a call would look
```

Prints:
        4

Does not operate exactly as you want it to but does the trick in my eyes.

Comment: The `(object)` inheritance seemed compulsory for an example of mine too.

Answer (score 2):

you could make the index into a tuple:
def **getitem**(self,indexTuple):
     x, y = indexTuple
     ...

and access the object override:
instance[[2,3]]
or
instance[(2,3)]

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I'll add my answer anyway for newcomers.
I ran into this need myself, and here's a solution that worked for me:

```
class Grid:

    def __init__(self):
        self.matrix = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
        self.second_access = False

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not self.second_access:
            self.first_key = key
            self.second_access = True
            return self
        else:
            self.second_access = False
            return self.matrix[self.first_key][key]


g = Grid()
print(g[1][2])  # 5
print(g[0][1])  # 1
print(g[2][0])  # 6
```

**Notice that this will not work for single access!**
So, for example, if you want to use something of the form `g[0]` to get `[0,1,2]` it will not work, and instead you'll get nonsensical result (the object itself).