# Pythonic API design (C# -like overriding of index operator?)

Tags: python

I have a Dungeon object which contains Rooms. Each Room has a name. I would like to design a class accepting this API from its clients:

```
dungeon = Dungeon()
room = dungeon.room['room_name']
```

So far, I was able to design something like this:

```
dungeon = Dungeon()
room = dungeon.room('room_name')
```

It is easy to just code a method that takes a str parameter and looks up the room by name.

But what if I wanted the room "accessor" to behave like a dictionary? What are my options?

I have thought of this but, being a true beginner, I can't decide:

- Create a subtype of dict, overriding its `__getattribute__` method

What I don't like, is for clients to be able to do this:

```
dungeon.room.keys()
```

and discover all of the room names, though.

If the question sounds silly to an expert... sorry. What else can I say?

Comment: You don't have to subclass `dict` to use [the various "get" protocols](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

Comment: Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000623/python-overloading-multiple-getitems-index-requests

Comment: If room names are valid Python identifiers, as would appear from your code, you can go one step ahead of C# and define a __getattr__ that gets it from a dict. Then you'd be able to access the room as `dungeon.room.room_name`, with actual rooms still being stored in an internal dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `__getitem____(self, key)` in your code - this gives you dictionary-style access to your object.

```
class Room(object):
    # stuff...
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # get room using the key and return the value
        # you should raise a KeyError if the value is not found
        return self.get_room(key)

dungeon.room = Room()
dungeon.room['room_name']  # this will work!
```

Comment: Small nitpick: technically, you're just defining `__getitem__`, you're not really overriding it. But +1 for the right answer and code sample.

Comment: Edited the answer for the sake of accuracy. :)